# How to activate company accounts through email after creating the company. RAILS

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

so this is my first question here in stackoverflow, i always find the answer by looking here... so.
I have this issue, I have a Model named Company, which can have many users, which would be the "best approach" to create and activate a user account within this newly created Company.

Here is the process i am following:
Platform Admin creates a company, the company serves as a grouping account in which i will have a number of users, but i need to send an Email after company creation to the Company admin in order to have him create his account so that he can manage the other company users, this email needs to have a hash so that it has some kind of reference to the company (avoiding the company selection in the form).

Im using Rails 4.2.6 and Angular 1.5

so im stuck after the company creation form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an email send the angular route url which got the company hash that just created. When admin user clicks on that link your angular route gets called and then before it render the view , i mean use resolve in angularjs route, get the list of all the user and company that just got created where admin user can select user that he or she want to activate.

Comment: But this assumes that the company Admin user is already created, which is not, after the company creation i send a mail with a link to the company admin through which he will create his account and then access the admin dashboard to do all the things a company admin does, like activate company users.